# Control the location of my IK bone

Tags: python, rigging, armature, bones, inverse-kinematics

I've created an IK bone for my left arm of my armature. I wonder how I can control it's location to be beside the armature around the hand. As shown below, when I grab it all the way it goes far from the armature and I want to avoid this? because I don't want the cube to be far from the armature once I grab then press left click.

[image]

Comment: with a  limit distance constraint?

Comment: @batFINGER thank you so much, that did it. Do you want to post an answer so I accept?